# goland check file type for xlsx

Tags: go, xlsx, file-type

Go standard library facility to check file type for xlsx file gives something like this

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("file_c.xlsx")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    defer f.Close()
    buf := make([]byte, 512)
    _, err = f.Read(buf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    contentType := http.DetectContentType(buf)
    fmt.Println(contentType)
}
```

and that prints:

```
application/zip
```

This package -> https://github.com/h2non/filetype

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/h2non/filetype"
)

func main() {
    buf, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("file_c.xlsx")
    kind, _ := filetype.Match(buf)
    if kind == filetype.Unknown {
        fmt.Println("unknown")
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("file type %s. MIME %s\n", kind.Extension, kind.MIME.Value)
}
```

prints:

```
file type xlsx. MIME application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

However when I have code like this:

```
// where file is of type *multipart.FileHeader
mpf, err := file.Open()
    if err != nil {
        wlog.Errorf("could not open %s file", file.Filename)
    } else {
        defer mpf.Close()
    }
buf := make([]byte, 512)
    _, err = mpf.Read(buf)
    if err != nil {
        wlog.Error("failed to read file")
    } else {
        kind, _ := filetype.Match(buf)
        if kind == filetype.Unknown {
            wlog.Info("unknown file type")
        } else {
            wlog.Infof("file type %s. MIME %s\n", kind.Extension, kind.MIME.Value)
        }
    }
```

prints:

```
file type zip. MIME application/zip
```

so information about xlsx file is lost somewhere in the middle even when I use this external code -> https://github.com/h2non/filetype
Do you have any idea why or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: xlsx, like lots of modern formats like ODF (ods, odt, odp, odg...), OOXML (docx, pptx, pptm, vsdx...), [OPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Packaging_Conventions), are just a zip file so the content must be extracted to identify the correct format

Answer (score 4):

This

```
buf, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("file_c.xlsx")
kind, _ := filetype.Match(buf)
```

works because it gets to scan the entire file. This

```
buf := make([]byte, 512)
// ...
kind, _ := filetype.Match(buf)
```

does not because it only gets to see the first 512 bytes, which is not enough to identify the file definitively as XLSX. An XLSX file is just a zip file with a certain pattern of contents, so it defaults to the more generic ZIP type (which is technically also correct).

[You can view the implementation](https://github.com/h2non/filetype/blob/d730d98ad5c990883148485b6fd5adbdd378364a/matchers/document.go#L90) to see just how much data it's scanning through to detect file type - up to several kilobytes.